# Consistency of the pooled standard deviation estimate

Tags: variance, asymptotics, consistency, pooling

Suppose that $X_{ik}\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ for $k = 1,2,\dots, n_i$ are independent and identically distributed for each $i \in\{ 1,2\}$. Note that I assume equal means ($0$) and variances ($\sigma^2$) across both groups. The standard t-test uses the pooled standard deviation $$s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{i=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik} - \overline X_{i\cdot})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^2n_i}}$$ with $\overline{X}_{i\cdot} = n_i^{-1}(X_{i1} + X_{i2} + \dots + X_{in_i})$ denoting the sample mean in the $i$th group. How can I show that $s$ is a consistent estimator for $\sigma$?

My attempt: Let $\varsigma_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik} - \overline{X}_{i\cdot})^2$ for $i = 1,2$. Then $$s^2 = \frac{\varsigma_1 + \varsigma_2}{n_1 + n_2} = \frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}\frac{\varsigma_1}{n_1} + \frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2}\frac{\varsigma_2}{n_2}.$$ [It can be shown that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496424/how-to-prove-s2-is-a-consistent-estimator-of-sigma2) $\frac{\varsigma_i}{n_i}$ converges in probability to $\sigma$. Thus, I need some additional assumptions on the asymptotic behavior of $\frac{n_i}{n_1 + n_2}$ to ensure that the above limit (in probability) exists, right? For example, I have to assume that $$\frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}$$ both converge to some (non-zero) constants $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as $n_i\rightarrow\infty$. Then $s^2$ converges in probability to $\lambda_1\sigma^2 + \lambda_2\sigma^2 = \sigma^2$ as $\lambda_1 = 1 - \lambda_2$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You only need both $n_1$ and $n_2$ to diverge, because $s^2$ is a weighted mean of two consistent estimators of $\sigma^2.$  Thus, when both the $n_i$ are large enough to put each estimator within $\epsilon$ of its limit (in any appropriate metric), the weighted mean will also be within $\epsilon$ of its limit. You don't need the proportions $n_i/(n_1+n_2)$ to converge.

Comment: @whuber: if the weighted mean was $w_1\frac{\varsigma_1}{n_1} + w_2\frac{\varsigma_2}{n_2}$ with $w_1$,$w_2$ deterministic and independend of both $n_i$s, I would agree. For instance, if $w_1 = 0.3$ if $n_1$ is even and $w_1 = 0.7$ if $n_1$ is odd, and $w_2 = 1 - w_1$, then the weights would jump between 0.3 and 0.7. So there must be something specific to my weights, I suppose. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the weights might jump up and down or even if one of them converges to zero.  *All* that matters is that both the $n_i$ diverge.

Comment: it's hard to me to see why. It would be nice if you could provide a formal proof of it

Comment: I did in my first comment.  All you need to know is an epsilon-delta definition of limit and apply it.

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$, and assume that both $P(\vert \hat\theta_1- \theta\vert > \epsilon)$ and $P(\vert \hat\theta_2- \theta\vert > \epsilon)$ converge to zero. I don't see how this helps me for $P(\vert  w_1\hat\theta_1+w_2\hat\theta_2- \theta\vert > \epsilon).$  (note that I used other symbols to save some space)

Comment: Rewrite the event as $|w_1(\hat\theta_1-\theta)+w_2(\hat\theta_2-\theta)|\gt \epsilon$ and invoke the convexity of the absolute value function.

Comment: I see, but this, implicitly, assumes that $w_1 + w_2 = 1$, as otherwise, I would not be able to rewrite the event as you described. Thank you!

Comment: That's not an assumption: it's an algebraic identity.  Maybe the problem is that there's a typographical error in the post, where "$n_1/(n_1+n_2)$" is repeated?  Besides, all that matters is that the $|w_i|$ are *bounded,* say by a number $M,$ because you can freely replace the arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon/M.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The weighted mean of consistent estimators is consistent

The pooled variance $s^2$ is a weighted mean of two consistent estimators for $\sigma^2$,
$$s^2=w_1s_1^2+w_2s_2^2,\quad s^2_i=\frac{1}{n_i}{\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik}-\overline{X}_{i.})^2},\quad w_i=\frac{n_i}{n_1+n_2},\quad i=1, 2.$$The weighted mean of consistent sequences of estimators $\hat\theta_{1,n}$ and $\hat\theta_{2,n}$ for a parameter $\theta$ is again consistent, for any sequence $(w_{1,n}, w_{2,n}=1-w_{1,n})_n$ of weights in $[0,1]$ (see @whuber's first comment)

###### Proof

By definition, a sequence of estimators $\hat\theta_n$ for $\theta$ is consistent if for any $\varepsilon>0$,  $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\hat\theta_{n}-\theta|<\varepsilon) = 1$. This means that for any $\delta >0$ we can find $n_0$ such that
$$
 P(|\hat\theta_{n}-\theta|<\varepsilon) > 1-\delta\quad\text{for all}\ \  n > n_0.
$$
Now, let $\hat\theta_n = w_{1,n}\hat\theta_{1,n}+w_{2,n}\hat\theta_{2,n}$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(|\hat\theta_{n}-\theta|<\varepsilon|)&= P(| w_{1,n}\hat\theta_{1,n}+w_{2,n}\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta|<\varepsilon)
\\&\geq P(| w_{1,n}(\hat\theta_{1,n}-\theta)|+|w_{2,n}(\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta)|<\varepsilon)
\\&\geq P(|\hat\theta_{1,n}-\theta|+|\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta)|<\varepsilon)
\\&\geq P(|\hat\theta_{1,n}-\theta|<\varepsilon/2 \wedge|\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta)|<\varepsilon/2)
\\&\geq P(|\hat\theta_{1,n}-\theta|<\varepsilon/2) + P(|\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta)|<\varepsilon/2) - 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since both $\hat\theta_{1,n}$ and $\hat\theta_{2,n}$ are consistent, we can to any $\delta >0$ find $n_0$ such that, for all $n>n_0$, both
$$
 P(|\hat\theta_{1,n}-\theta|<\varepsilon/2)>1-\frac{\delta}{2} \quad\text{and}\quad P(|\hat\theta_{2,n}-\theta|<\varepsilon/2)>1-\frac{\delta}{2}, 
$$ and thus also $P(|\hat\theta_{n}-\theta|<\varepsilon) > 1-\delta$ .$\quad\Box$

Answer (score 4):

No: convergence of $n_1/(n_1+n_2)$ is sufficient but it isn't necessary, because the limit doesn't depend on $n_1/(n_1+n_2)$.

Suppose $n_i\to\infty$.
Every subsequence ($n_{1,j},n_{2,j}$) has a subsubsequence ($n_{1,j_k},n_{2,j_k}$) such that $n_{1,j_k}/(n_{1,j_k}+n_{2,j_k})\to c\in [0,1]$. Along this subsequence, you have convergence of $s^2_{j_k}$ to $\sigma^2$ in probability, which implies $s^2_i\stackrel{p}{\to}\sigma^2$ for the whole sequence.

Comment: what is the reason that every subsequence has a subsequence such that the ratio converges to some $c$?

Comment: @Syd Because $[0,1]$ is compact.  But this fact isn't necessary, as my comment to your question indicates.

Comment: The limit $c$ could vary between subsequences, e.g. for (1,1)(1,2),(2,2),(2,4),(4,4),... convergent subsequences can have c=1/2 or  c=1/3. But as @whuber said, it is not necessary for the weights to converge, since you are taking the weighted mean of two consistent estimators that both converge to the same $\sigma^2$.